# «А, ну, да...» запятые

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> А, ну, да, когда я ел в последний раз?

Все ли тут верно? Или есть лишние запятые?

Answer (score 1):

**А, ну да, когда я ел в последний раз?**

1) **А** ― **междометие**, в данном случае выражает  **припоминание**, обособляется

2) **Ну да**, частица (в начале реплики). Разг. 1. Употр. для выражения подчёркнутого согласия, для утвердительного ответа; конечно. Ты сделал то, что тебя просили? ― **Ну да**, давно. Вы его знаете? ― **Ну да,** знаем.